# Ghost table border in FireFox 6 when setting the border-width to 2px

Tags: css, firefox

Compare the following two examples in FireFox 6:

- http://jsfiddle.net/utKw9/7/
- http://jsfiddle.net/utKw9/9/

The only difference is the border-width changed from 1px to 2px. But this results into a ghost border displayed across a "row-span" cell to the right from the cell where we have set the border width.

Is it a FireFox 6 bug? Will they fix it? Is there solution to overcome this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no bug with FF. You should change your CSS code. Please change to `border-width: 2px;` then you wont see the ghost border.

Comment: I do think this is buggy. It does not appear in Chrome for example, and it appears when you add multiple rows... also it is a `TD` border where shouldn't be any cell's border.

Comment: No, `border-bottom-width: 2px;` results into the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/utKw9/13/; `border-width: 2px; border-style: none none solid none;` displays a ghost border either

Comment: if you add `.name{
    border-color: blue;
}` it is clearly wrong.